# Unimodular matrices and row operations

Tags: matrices, abelian-groups, bilinear-form, unimodular-matrices

Is it true that any unimodular matrix can be transformed into the identity matrix using only elementary row operations, i.e. multiplying a row by $-1$, exchanging two rows or summing one row to another? I cannot find a counterexample, so I suppose it is true, but I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: Where are living the coefficients of your matrix ? $\mathbb{Z}$ ? any commutative ring ? if this is $\mathbb{Z}$, the answer is yes , and you can  find plenty of proofs on the web. In the second case, there are counterexamples.

Comment: My matrix has coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$, but I was not able to find a proof. Have you got a reference?